# Different behavior of XmlPullParser.getInputEncoding() on API11+ and pre-API11 versions of Android

Tags: android, xml, encoding, filereader, fileinputstream

I am developing a new feature for my android app to enable data backup and restore. I am using XML files to backup data. This is a piece of code that sets encoding for an output file:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file, false);
serializer.setOutput(fileWriter);
serializer.startDocument("UTF-8", true);
[... Write data to the file....]
```

This is how I try to import data from an XML file. First, I check if the encoding is correct:

```
XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
parser.setInput(reader);
if(!"UTF-8".equals(parser.getInputEncoding())) {
    throw new IOException("Incorrect file encoding");
}
[... Read data from the file....]
```

And here I'm running into a problem. This code works fine on Android 2.3.3(both a device and an emulator), the encoding is correctly detected as "UTF-8". But on API11+ versions(Honeycomb, ICS, JB) the exception is thrown. When I run this in debug mode I can see that parser.getInputEncoding() returns `null`. I checked the actual XML files produced on 2.3.3 and later versions and they have exactly the same headers: `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>`. **Why does getInputEncoding() return null on API11+?**

**Additional findings:**

I have discovered that there is a way to correctly detect file encoding on API11+ devices using `FileInputStream` instead of `FileReader` like this:

```
XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
parser.setInput(stream, null);
if(!"UTF-8".equals(parser.getInputEncoding())) {
    throw new IOException("Incorrect file encoding");
}
[... Read data from the file....]
```

In this case getInputEncoding() properly detects UTF-8 encoding on API11+ emulators and devices, but it returns null on 2.3.3. So for now I can insert a fork in code to use FileReader on API11+ and FileInputStream on pre-API11:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    parser.setInput(stream, null);
} else {
    parser.setInput(reader);
}
```

**But what's the proper way to check encoding with XmlPullParser.getInputEncoding()? Why are different versions of Android behave differently depending on which one I use: FileInputStream or FileReader?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some more trial and error, I've finally managed to figure out what's going on. So despite the fact that [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html) says:

> Historically Android has had two implementations of this interface:
>   KXmlParser via XmlPullParserFactory.newPullParser(). 
>   ExpatPullParser, via Xml.newPullParser().
>
> Either choice is fine. The example in this section uses ExpatPullParser, via Xml.newPullParser().

The reality is, that on older APIs, such as 2.3.3 `Xml.newPullParser()` returns `ExpatPullParser` object. While on Ice Cream Sandwich and up it returns `KXmlParser` object. And as we can see from [this blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/12/watch-out-for-xmlpullparsernexttext.html), android developers knew about this since December 2011:

> In Ice Cream Sandwich we changed Xml.newPullParser() to return a KxmlParser and deleted our ExpatPullParser class.

...but never bothered to update the official documentation.

So how do you retrieve `KXmlParser` object on APIs before Ice Cream Sandwich? Simple:

```
XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();
```

...in fact this works on all versions of android, new and old. Then you supply a FileInputStream to your parser's setInput() method, leaving default encoding `null`:

```
FileInputStream stream = null;
stream = new FileInputStream(file);
parser.setInput(stream, null);
```

After this, on APIs 11 and higher you can call parser.getInputEncoding() right away and it will return the correct encoding. But on pre-API11 versions, it will return null unless you call parser.next() first, as @Esailija correctly pointed out in his answer. Interestingly enough, on API11+ calling next() doesn't have any negative effect whatsoever, so you may safely use this code on all versions:

```
parser.next();
String encoding = parser.getInputEncoding();
```

And this will correctly return "UTF-8".

Answer (score 0):

`FileReader` and other readers don't detect encoding. They just use the platform default encoding which can be UTF-8 by coincidence. It has no relation to the actual encoding of the file.

You cannot detect XML file encoding until you read it enough to see the `encoding` attribute.

From [`getInputEncoding()` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html#getInputEncoding())

> if inputEncoding is null **and the parser supports the encoding
>   detection feature**, it must return the detected encoding

And:

> If setInput(Reader) was called, null is returned.

So it appears that pre 11 doesn't support detection which is enabled by using `setInput(is, null)`. I don't know how you are getting `"UTF-8"` when using `setInput(reader)` as the documentation says it should return `null`.

Then:

> After first call to next if XML declaration was present this method
>   will return encoding declared.

So in pre 11, you could try calling `.next()` intially before calling `.getInputEncoding`

Comment: I tried following your instructions, but calling .next() on pre-API11 doesn't help, getInputEncoding() keeps returning `null`.

Comment: Please take a look at my answer to the question. You were right about calling `.next()`, but there was a second piece: I should have used `XmlPullParserFactory.newPullParser()` instead of `Xml.newPullParser()`. And use `FileInputStream` instead of `FileReader`, of course.