# Best way to parse this XML on android?

Tags: android, xml, parsing, url

I ran into a issue where I cant help myself and there wont come any help from the back end.

This is the story: I need to parse a XML from a URL.

The URL is: http://deliveroid.techhouse.sk/admin/restapi/company/62?userid=DFDJHGJDHGFFHH

Once you open it in a browser all looks good. Yet when I try to parse it within android (XmlPullParser) I get a error - the encoding is not right.

I have no idea what causes it and if its the server issue I wont have a chance to influence the situation..

Is there a way how to "force" the UTF-8 and make it parse able? Could someone show me how he would tackle this? One xml value lets say   and you would save my day ..

Thank you

Comment: this question may be able to help solve your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009344/different-behavior-of-xmlpullparser-getinputencoding-on-api11-and-pre-api11-v

Comment: Can you please post the logcat and the code you are using so that we can see what the error could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define encoding before parsing it.

```
XmlPullParser pullParser = Xml.newPullParser();
pullParser.setInput(theInputStream, "UTF-8");
```

Hope it helps